# Roles of backbone views, model, and router

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I am developing a backbone application which is using require.js.

I want a user to enter in the 'id' for a model and then either be redirected to a view for that model if it exists, or display an error message if it does not. This sounds extremely simple, but I am having trouble figuring out the roles of each component.

In the application below, the user will come to an index page with an input (with id 'modelId') and a button (with class attribute 'lookup').

The following piece of code is the router.

```
define(['views/index', 'views/myModelView', 'models/myModel'], 
    function(IndexView, MyModelView, myModel) {
    var MyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        currentView: null,

        routes: {
            "index": "index",
            "view/:id": "view"
        },

        changeView: function(view) {
            if(null != this.currentView) {
                this.currentView.undelegateEvents();
            }
            this.currentView = view;
            this.currentView.render();
        },

        index: function() {
            this.changeView(new IndexView());
        },

        view: function(id) {
            //OBTAIN MODEL HERE?
            //var model
            roter.changeView(new MyModelView(model))
        }

    });

    return new MyRouter();
});
```

The following piece of code is the index view

```
define(['text!templates/index.html', 'models/myModel'], 
    function( indexTemplate, MyModel) {
    var indexView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#content'),

        events: {
            "click .lookup": "lookup"
        },

        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(indexTemplate);
            $("#error").hide();
        },

        lookup: function(){
            var modelId = $("#modelId").val()
            var model = new MyModel({id:modelId});
            model.fetch({
                success: function(){
                    window.location.hash = 'view/'+model.id;
                },
                error: function(){
                    $("#error").text('Cannot view model');
                    $("#error").slideDown();
                }
            });
        },
    });
    return indexView
});
```

What I can't figure out is that it seems like the better option is for the index view to look up the model (so it can display an error message if the user asks for a model that doesn't exist, and also to keep the router cleaner). But the problem is that the router now has no reference to the model when the view/:id router is triggered. How is it supposed to get a hold of the model in the view() function?

I guess it could do another fetch, but that seems redundant and wrong. Or maybe there is supposed to be some global object that both the router and the view share (that the index view could put the model in), but that seems like tight coupling.

Comment: the router can have a collection of models , just query the collection  for the right model. that is what collections are for.

Comment: But how is the collection shared between the 'index view'( which does the work of obtaining the model) and the router (which gives the model to the view that is supposed to display it)?

Comment: the collection can be a property of the router, you can pass it in the initialize function , then use this.collection or whatever , do you understand ? you are talking about tight coupling but if you do dependency injection there is not tight coupling.

Comment: imagine you do something like "new MyRouter(myCollection)" or something then use this.myCollection inside the router. edit : it should not be up to the view to fetch models or whatever ,at some point you need some kind of mediator outside the view ,broadcast events from the view to the mediator (the router in that case) then the router tells models and collections to fetch datas.

Comment: Oh I think so. So I create the collection in the router and then pass the collection to the indexView. The indexView then puts a model in the collection in the 'lookup()' method. Then when the router calls the 'view()' method, the model will be there since it is shared.  Is that right?

Comment: yes , you can do that. dont be afraid of really declouping components with event broadcasting , you components can listen each other ( or you can use the Event class to create a dumb mediator that does nothing else than suscribing and publishing events ) through your application , it will allow you to implement the Command Pattern with backbone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this.  You could do something similar with a collection instead of a model, but it seems like you don't want to fetch/show the whole collection?

With this type of solution (I think similar to what @mpm was suggesting), your app will handle browser refreshes, back/forward navigation properly.  You basically have a MainView, which really acts more like a app controller.  It handles events triggered either by the router, or by user interaction (clicking lookup or a back-to-index button on the item view).

Credit to [Derick Bailey](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/08/28/dont-execute-a-backbone-js-route-handler-from-your-code/) for a lot of these ideas.

In the Router. These are now only triggered if the user navigates by changing a URL or back/forward.

```
    index: function() {
        Backbone.trigger('show-lookup-view');
    },

    view: function(id) {
        var model = new MyModel({id: id});
        model.fetch({
            success: function(){
                Backbone.trigger('show-item-view', model);
            },
            error: function(){
                // user could have typed in an invalid URL, do something here,
                // or just make the ItemView handle an invalid model and show that view...
            }
        });
    }
```

In new MainView, which you would create on app startup, not in router:

```
el: 'body',

initialize: function (options) {
    this.router = options.router;

    // listen for events, either from the router or some view.
    this.listenTo(Backbone, 'show-lookup-view', this.showLookup);
    this.listenTo(Backbone, 'show-item-view', this.showItem);
},

changeView: function(view) {
    if(null != this.currentView) {
       // remove() instead of undelegateEvents() here
       this.currentView.remove();
    }
    this.currentView = view;
    this.$el.html(view.render().el);
},

showLookup: function(){
    var view = new IndexView();
    this.changeView(view);
    // note this does not trigger the route, only changes hash.
    // this ensures your URL is right, and if it was already #index because
    // this was triggered by the router, it has no effect.
    this.router.navigate('index'); 
},

showItem: function(model){
    var view = new ItemView({model: model});
    this.changeView(view);
    this.router.navigate('items/' + model.id); 
}
```

Then in IndexView, you trigger the 'show-item-view' event with the already fetched model.

```
    lookup: function(){
        var modelId = $("#modelId").val()
        var model = new MyModel({id:modelId});
        model.fetch({
            success: function(){
                Backbone.trigger('show-item-view', model);
            },
            error: function(){
                $("#error").text('Cannot view model');
                $("#error").slideDown();
            }
        });
    },
```

I don't think this is exactly perfect, but I hope it could point you in a good direction.